# Error en java con escribir en fichero

Tags: java

Estoy intentando crear un programa en java que cuando introduzca una palabra de 5 letras  me compare si las letras son iguales a una palabra aleatoria y luego escriba el resultado en un fichero, pero me da este error y no entiendo por qué no va, si además estoy capturando los errores con un `try` y un `catch`.

Mi código:

```java
Cogemos los paquetes

package curso;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

#Aquí creamos mi clase main donde está el array de las palabras aleatorias y funciona cogiendo una plabra y probando con cada letra si coincide

public class main {
    El array de la palabra aleatoria
    public static List<String> getPalabras(){
        return Arrays.asList("coche",
                            "ambar",
                            "raton",
                            "pizza",
                            "perro",
                            "pasta",
                            "quien",
                            "cromo",
                            "salto",
                            "donde",
                            "falta",
                            "barco",
                            "balsa",
                            "guiar",
                            "horno",
                            "lugar",
                            "mirar",
                            "naipe",
                            "pinta",
                            "rural",
                            "sonar",
                            "tocar",
                            "tener",
                            "letra",
                            "igual",
                            "tonto",
                            "total",
                            "bombo",
                            "morir",
                            "motin",
                            "matiz",
                            "mundo",
                            "grupo",
                            "saber",
                            "cinco",
                            "hacer",
                            "perla",
                            "dejar",
                            "epoca",
                            "sobre",
                            "gesto",
                            "rival",
                            "lunes",
                            "nadie",
                            "paron",
                            "ideal",
                            "gasto",
                            "renta",
                            "hasta",
                            "hacia");

    }

    public static void main (String[] args ){
    
    Escritura del fichero  usando filewriter
    
    FileWriter archivo;
    try {
        archivo = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\alber\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\fichero.txt");
    
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(archivo);
    
    
    int elegida = (int) (Math.random() * 50);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese una palabra");
     String palabra = scanner.next();
    Aquí es donde compruebo que tengo 5 letras
        if (palabra.length()== 5) {
            
                Aquí hago la comparación letra por letra
                for(int i=0; i < palabra.length();i++) {
                    if(palabra.charAt(i)==getPalabras().get(elegida).charAt(i)) {
                        System.out.println(palabra.charAt(i) + "Es igual "  + getPalabras().get(elegida).charAt(i));
                        bw.write(palabra.charAt(i) + "Es igual "  + getPalabras().get(elegida).charAt(i));
                        bw.close();
                    }else {
                        
                        System.out.println(palabra.charAt(i)+ " " + "No es igual " + " " + getPalabras().get(elegida).charAt(i));
                        bw.write(palabra.charAt(i) + "Es igual "  + getPalabras().get(elegida).charAt(i));
                        bw.close();
                    }
                }
                    
            }
        
        else{
            int intentos=0;
            boolean resultado = false;
            while(resultado == false || intentos <= 5) {
                intentos ++;
                System.out.println("Ingrese una palabra");
                palabra = scanner.nextLine();
                if(palabra.length()==5) {
                     resultado = true;
                    
                }
                
            }
                if(intentos==5) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Has fallado el juego vuelva a intentarlo");
                }
                
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

---

```
Este es el fallo
Ingrese una palabra
adios
a No es igual  h
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
d No es igual  o
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:107)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:224)
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
    at arrays/curso.main.main(main.java:93)
```

Comment: Puedes [edit] la pregunta para añadir información, no uses el apartado de respuestas para ello, por favor. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y leas [ask]

Comment: En lugar de agregar ruido a la pregunta, mejora la redacción de la misma. Además, no escribiste el mensaje de error. Lee [ask].

Comment: mezclar código con comentarios sin formato de comentario `//comentario` es una pésima idea. Nadie va a poder replicar tu problema sin ir viendo qué falla

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo. Tienes unos `for` y en cada iteración escribes y luego cierras. La segunda iteración del ciclo for, el bufferedwriter ya está cerrado y no puedes escribir.

Esa instrucción `bw.close()` va al finaaaaaaaaaaaaaal de todo, ojalá en un finally de ese try-catch (revisa cómo funciona) y con eso aseguras que cierras todo al final de la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho